# Chain nested SCSS argements

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Is there any solution how to convert this:

```
[class*="needle"]:not([class*="__front"], [class*="__back"]) {
  position: absolute;
}
```

to this:

```
[class*="needle"]:not([class*="__front"]):not([class*="__back"]) {
  position: absolute; }
```

using a SCSS compiler?

I only get:

```
[class*="needle"]:not([class*="__front"], [class*="__back"]) {
  position: absolute;
}
```

that cannot be interpreted by most browsers.
Many thanks.

Comment: Can you please share some html on which you are applying this code. So that before providing the solution we can try ourself.

Comment: This code is not yet in use. I just want to compile it  right (e.g. using gulp-sass).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make use of SCSS for the reason it developed, to make syntax pretty and easy to understand.

```
[class*="needle"]{
    &:not([class*="__front"]){
        &:not([class*="__back"]) {
              position: absolute;
        }
    }
}
```

Should work. Here, `&` is used to  refer the parent. Once you compile it, the resulting CSS would be

```
[class*="needle"]:not([class*="__front"]):not([class*="__back"]) {
  position: absolute; 
}
```

---

Sorry, I read the question wrong. The above conversion is not possible in `SCSS`, as that's neither proper `CSS` syntax nor `SCSS` syntax.

Currently, `:not()` selector does only simple matches. The above syntax is a valid one for level 4 selectors, which is in working draft and mostly not available in any browsers.

---

Also,

```
<Selector>:not(<Condition1>):not(<Condition2>) {
  position: absolute; 
}
```

is not ,

```
<Selector>:not(<Condition1>,<Condition2>) {
  position: absolute; 
}
```

where as first method acts as `AND`, second one acts as `OR`.

- [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)
- [W3C Docs](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation)

Comment: Well this is nice but my current code is based on a template I need to update everytime an update appears. I don't want to change to code every time. My aim is to detect a compiler or a compiler option that can handle this.

Comment: Thank you, you'r right. :not() uses :matches() which equals an OR matching list.
Qrazy is, that the gulp file generated the chained method (:not(...):not(...)) while my compiler compiles the OR syntax that is only working on Safari. So I have to contact the support of the Template-team to take a look on this.